# BufferedReader.readline() returns null

Tags: java

BufferedReader returns null and i don't understand why.
I have a ClientServer app with GUI interface and it works good, but in this method
idk why in loop msgFromServer has value = null because br.readline() returns it.

```
      try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), true);
        pw.println("refreshRoomOnClient"); 
        countClientInRoomFromServer = br.readLine(); 
        lblCountClientInRoom.setText("Clients in the room: " + countClientInRoomFromServer);
        pw.println(txtNameRoom.getText());
        listModelRoom.removeAllElements();
        int size_listModelRoom = listModelRoom.size();
        String msgFromServ;
          while (!"exit".equals(msgFromServ = br.readLine())) {
            System.out.println(msgFromServ);
            if ("Cant find File".equals(msgFromServ)) {
                txtLogs.append("Can't find files" + "\n");
                break;
            } else if ("error".equals(msgFromServ)) {
                txtLogs.append("Error reading" + "\n");
                break;
            }
            listModelRoom.insertElementAt(msgFromServ, size_listModelRoom);
        }
      } catch (IOException ex) {
        txtLogs.append("btnRefreshCountClientInRoomActionPerformed..." + "\n");
    }
```

Comment: As [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()), `BufferedReader` returns null at the end of the stream - in this case, if the socket has been closed. You haven't presented us enough context to know why that would be unexpected.

Comment: Also it is *never* a good idea to not do anything with the Exception that was caught in a `catch` block. At least call `e.printStackTrace()`.

Comment: I have 1000 lines of code there, the problem is only in this place, this is the button to which we assign the action. I'm not closing the socket in the code, it's a separate method

Comment: It would be the *other end* of the connection that's closing the socket. No-one is suggesting that you post 1000 lines of code, but you haven't explained enough about the app to tell us why you think it's unreasonable for `BufferedReader.readLine` to return null.

Comment: As @JonSkeet says, you need `while ((msgFromServ = br.readLine()) != null && !(msgFromServer.equals("exit")))`